# Extract all HTML tags from string

Tags: python, html, r

How would I go about extracting all the HTML tags (everything that begins with a < and ends with a >) from a string? I want all of the starting tags in one column and all of the ending tags in another. Here's an example...

If I start with ...

`<span class="TextRun MacChromeBold SCXW77287090 BCX0" data-contrast="none" lang="EN-US"><span class="NormalTextRun SCXW77287090 BCX0">What is your age in years? Are you</span></span><br>`

I want to end with one column that has...

`<span class="TextRun MacChromeBold SCXW77287090 BCX0" data-contrast="none" lang="EN-US"><span class="NormalTextRun SCXW77287090 BCX0">`

And another that has...

`</span></span><br>`

The goal is to make it much easier to replace the text in the middle.

Thanks!

Comment: You are making this harder than it needs to be. If you want to replace text inside html, use a dedicated html parser like `xml2`- this would be far quicker and more reliable.